# Kotlin: why do constructor parameters have "internal" visibility by default?

Tags: constructor, kotlin, visibility

If we have a class:

```
class Customer(val customerName: String) { }
```

Its contructor parameter `customerName` is accessible through `getCustomerName()` (because it's also a property). If we want to restrict access to this property we should declare it as `private`.

Since in many cases from Java world (and if a class is not intended to be data class) fields which are assigned from constructor parameters are for private / protected use it feels like an additional effort to explicitely declare them `private` in Kotlin.

Also, Kotlin classes are final by default, so why not follow this principle for properties? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

In our experience, and from some empirical studies of existing codebases, `internal`/`public` visibility is best for properties.

> Also, Kotlin classes are final by default, so why not follow this principle for properties? Am I missing something?

Properties are `final` by default, i.e. they can not be overridden unless you supply the `open` modifier explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A Protected Modifier in Kotlin: CANNOT be set on top-level declarations. Declarations that are protected in a class, can be accessed only in their subclasses.

for more details you can use [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-visibility-modifiers-public-protected-internal-private)